# Проблема с boolean-ом в C++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, рекурсия, компилятор

```
static bool wheel_scrolled_up(SDL_Event event);
```

Почему этот boolean может запуститься без `SDL_Event event`, когда должен только с `SDL_Event event`?

Пример:

```
#include <AceEngine/AceEngine.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SDL_Event event;

int main()
{
    if (ACE::mouse::wheel_scrolled_up/* (SDL_Event event) */)
        cout << "Wheel scrolled up!" << endl;
}
```

Этот код не выдаёт при компиляций никаких ощибок, когда он должен выдовать!

По настоящему должно быть так:

```
#include <AceEngine/AceEngine.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SDL_Event event;

int main()
{
    if (ACE::mouse::wheel_scrolled_up(event))
        cout << "Wheel scrolled up!" << endl;
}
```

Я не знаю это баг или нет, но так не должно быть!

Как сделать так чтобы без `SDL_Event event` компилятор выдовал ощибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код формально валиден и не должен генерировать ошибку. Имя `ACE::mouse::wheel_scrolled_up` без скобочек может рассматриваться как указатель на функцию и внутри `if` преобразуется в `bool`. Хотя такая запись валидна, она не не имеет большого смысла, так как результат такого преобразования известен на этапе компиляции, что делает `if` фактически бессмысленным. Во многих компиляторах есть соотв. предупреждение на такой случай (`warning C4551`, `-Wpointer-bool-conversion`), которое имеет смысл включить и (опционально) перевести в категорию ошибок.

```
void foo(int) {}

int main()
{
    if (foo) // error: address of function 'foo' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Werror,-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Pv44dW

Comment: Тоесть так и должно быть? )

Comment: @RedBull4 Ну как бы в С++ ответственность за корректность в основном лежит на программисте, а компилятор жалуется в крайних случаях.

Answer (score 2):

`ACE::mouse::wheel_scrolled_up` - это не вызов, а по сути адрес функции, каковой явно не `nullptr`, а значит, вы написали `if (true) ...` (при приведении адреса в `bool`).

**Вызов** всегда требует наличия скобок! То, что вы считаете "вызовом без `event`", имело бы вид

```
ACE::mouse::wheel_scrolled_up()
```

Comment: Так рекурсия без event работает, а Я хочу чтобы работало только с event-ом, иначе компилятор должен выдать ощибку.

Comment: Где у вас рекурсия? И почему компилятор должен выдавать ошибку на синтаксически корректное выражение? По-моему, вы вообще не поняли, что я написал в ответе...

Comment: Ощибся, это boolean )

Comment: Принципиально это ничего не меняет. У вас есть проверка - не по нулевому ли адресу находится функция? очевидно, что нет. Ваше требование - примерно как "я хочу, чтобы для переменных `int a,b;` было разрешено `a+b`, но на `a-b` компилятор выводил бы сообщение об ошибке"...